# Sum consecutive even numbers and consecutive odd numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code that sums the consecutive `even` numbers and consecutive `odd` numbers, then adds them to an `arraylist`. This process should be repeated until there are no more consecutive odd or even numbers in the list. Then returns the size of the `arraylist`.

I used nested `for` loops and the problem is the loops check the same `index` which doesn't make sense.

Here's my code:

```
public static int SumGroups(int[] arr) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int even = 0, odd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                even += arr[i];
                if (arr[j] % 2 == 0) {
                    even += arr[j];
                } else {
                    arl.add(even);
                    even = 0;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                odd += arr[i];
                if (arr[j] % 2 != 0) {
                    odd += arr[j];
                } else {
                    arl.add(odd);
                    odd = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arl.size();
}
```

**My Question is:**
How to prevent loops from checking the same index ?
in other words, how to make my code sums the consecutive even numbers and consecutive odd numbers ?

**Input:**

```
int arr[]={2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 9};
```

**Output:**

```
6 // [2, 1, 10, 5, 30, 15]
```

Comment: I updated the post to explain my question

Comment: can you provide sample input and desired output?

Comment: @DavidMatriguet you're output is incorrect, it should be 8 [2, 1, 10, 5, 2, 24, 4, 15}

Comment: @Lashane No, Because 2,24, and 4 are 3 consecutive even numbers

Comment: @DavidMatriguet 2,24(5+5+7+7),4 are not numbers in input array, they are result sums, do you mean that we should run new array through the same function again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88268/discussion-between-david-matriguet-and-lashane).

Answer (score 4):

```
I think the following code should solve the problem, if you do not want to output the size simply return `sums` instead of `sums.size()`

 public static int sumGroupsRecursively(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> numbersToSum = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> currentSumList = sumSublist(numbersToSum);
        List<Integer> nextSumList = sumSublist(currentSumList);

        while (currentSumList.size() != nextSumList.size()) {
            currentSumList = nextSumList;
            nextSumList = sumSublist(currentSumList);
        }

        return nextSumList.size();
    }


  public static List<Integer> sumSublist(List<Integer> list) {
        int current = list.get(0);
        int currentSum = 0;
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (current % 2 == list.get(i) % 2) {
                currentSum += list.get(i);
            } else {
                sums.add(currentSum);
                current = list.get(i);
                currentSum = current;
            }
        }
        sums.add(currentSum);
        return sums;
    }
```

If you need to do this in one function what I would discourage because it is harder to read you could use code like this.

```
public static Integer sumSublist(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    sums.add(0);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length - 1) {
        int current = arr[i];
        int currentSum = 0;
        while (current % 2 == arr[i] % 2) {
            currentSum += arr[i];
            if (i >= arr.length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (currentSum % 2 == sums.get(sums.size()-1) % 2) {
            sums.set(sums.size() - 1, sums.get(sums.size()-1) + currentSum);
        } else {
            sums.add(currentSum);
        }
    }
    return sums.size();
}
```

Comment: if this solved your question, think about marking the answer as acccepted

Answer (score 0):

You are entering your first for loop passing in arr.  Inside the first for loop you enter a second for loop passing in arr a second time.   This means that you enter the second for loop as many times as there are elements in arr and transverse arr in the second for loop every single time.

for example, if arr.length() was 2 you would transverse arr 3 times.  Once in your outer for loop and twice (once for each element in arr) in your inner loop.

Second, by adding both the odd and even numbers to your arraylist, you are doing nothing but reconstructing arr but in an arraylist rather than array.  Therefor, returning arl.size() is the exact same as returning arr.length() which is already known and much easier to do.

Despite that, here is how I would calculate the sum of the odd and evens.  I add both to different arraylists.  You'll need to figure out exactly what you need to return though because your description is off.

```
public void test(){

int[] arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;

int testOfEven = 6;
int testOfOdd = 9;
int sumOfEven = 0;
int sumOfOdd = 0;

ArrayList evens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  if ((arr[i]%2) == 0)
  {
    evens.add(arr[i]);
    sumOfEven += arr[i];
  }
  else
  {
    odds.add(arr[i]);
    sumOfOdd += arr[i];
  }
}

assertEquals(testOfEven, sumOfEven);
assertEquals(testOfOdd, sumOfOdd);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

after playing some time, here is my version:

```
public static int SumGroups(final int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        int n, sum, psum;
        psum = sum = n = arr[0] & 1; // parity of first number in sequence
        int s = 1; // at least one element in array
        int f = 0; // discard first parity change
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (n == (arr[i] & 1)) {
                sum = (sum + n) & 1; // both even or odd, just increase sum
            } else {
                s += (psum ^ sum) & f; // compare sums parity
                psum = sum; // store current sum's parity
                sum = n = arr[i] & 1; // new first number in sequence
                f = 1; // do not discard sums parity next time
            }
        }
        s += (psum ^ sum) & f; // array ended, check parity of last sum
        return s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've put comments, but still some additional notes:

1. basic idea is the same as @PKuhn, just checked for some edge cases (empty array, integer overflow)
2. we don't need to have array of sums, we need just previous sum and check parity of it with newly calculated one
3. `sum = (sum + n) & 1` - we don't need to calculate whole sum, we need just parity of the sum
4. `s += (psum ^ sum) & f` - we need to increase swap counter only if parity changed, xor helps us to get 1 if changed and 0 if not

Here is the list of tests which I've used:

```
    Assert.assertEquals(6, SumGroups(new int[] { 2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 9 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(6, SumGroups(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 9 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { 2, 3, 3 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { 2, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, SumGroups(new int[] { 3, 2, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, SumGroups(new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 2, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, SumGroups(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { 3, 3, 2, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 2 }));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, SumGroups(new int[] { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 3 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

public  void findEvenOdd(int a[]){

```
    Boolean flip = false;
    int sum = 0, i, m = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (flip) {
    System.out.print(sum + "\t");
    sum = a[i];
    flip = !flip;
    if (i + 1 < a.length && (a[i] % 2 != a[i + 1] % 2))
    flip = !flip;
    m++;
    } else {
    sum += a[i];
    if (i + 1 < a.length && (a[i] % 2 != a[i + 1] % 2))
    flip = !flip;
    m++;
    }

    }

    if(m!=a.length-1)
    System.out.print(a[a.length-1] + "\t");
    }
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.